# postgres pg_column_compression is giving error: No function matches the given name and argument types?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

My Postgres DB version is **13.5**.

When I run -

```
SELECT  pg_column_size(jdoc) FROM dataingest.refresh limit 10;
```

I am getting result as expected.

```
pg_column_size|
--------------+
          2523|
          2530|
```

But when I run -

```
SELECT  pg_column_compression(jdoc) FROM dataingest.refresh limit 2;
```

I am facing below error.

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function pg_column_compression(jsonb) does
> not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument
> types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

What could be issue and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_column_compression` was introduced in Postgres 14, so it's not available in Postgres 13 which is the version you are using.

The only way to "fix" this is to upgrade to Postgres 14 or 15

Comment: `upgrade to Postgres 14 or 15` - will try if I see other benefits for my use case. +1